# Select n objects randomly from a django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In Django, How can i select n random objects in no particular order **out of a queryset** (already pulled out from the database) of say m objects (ofcourse m>n)?

There can be many ways but is there a django specific way for this?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question. I already have a queryset selecte. Out of that i want to select random objects

Comment: If you already have a queryset you could still do `order_by('?')` and then get n random objects.

Comment: Yes, you can do order_by('?')[:n] to get the required result. If the queryset is large and you have to select a small number then you can select n random numbers between 0 and (m-1) and the do list operations to get those particular entries from the queryset